# Converting a timestamp string to UNIX timestamp in MonetDB

Tags: sql, unix-timestamp, monetdb

I'd like to convert a timestamp like "2018-02-14 23:59:59" to a UNIX timestamp. I found that the opposite is possible using `select sys.epoch(unix_timestamp);`.
The functions `str_to_date`, `str_to_time` or `str_to_timestamp` are of no help, even if I specify the format string "%s" as seen [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/DateTimeFunctionality#DateandTimefunctionality-Date/timeformatspecifiers).

In other words, I'm looking for the MonetDB equivalent of the MySQL function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
select sys.epoch(str_to_timestamp('2018-02-15 10:04:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'));
```

> 1518689040

Obviously, if you need this in milliseconds, just multiply by 1000 like so:

```
select sys.epoch(str_to_timestamp('2018-02-15 10:04:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) * 1000;
```

How I found it, in case anyone has a similar problem in the future:

You can view all system functions using:

```
select * from sys.functions;
```

A prettier solution can be found here: [Is there a way to view MonetDB Function signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733504/is-there-a-way-to-view-monetdb-function-signatures)

It turns out the epoch function can take a timestamp as a parameter.